# How does the C# Random class work

Tags: c#, random

I wanted to understand how the C# `Random.next()` worked so I started searching up some things and I red it gets a random seed from the clock like this: `DateTime.Now.Millisecond`. So I thought if you create a lot of Random objects in a row it will spit out the same number, I wanted to check that and created this code snippet.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rn;
            while (true)
            {
                rn = new Random();
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(rn.Next(10));
            }

        }
```

And when I ran this I got of course a lot of number which where the same, but what I thought was when the `DateTime.Now.Millisecond` is going to change, it also will change the random number, but this is not the case as you can see in this output.

```
9
127
9
127
9
127
9
127
9
127
9
127
9
127
9
128
9
128
9
128
9
128
9
128
9
```

So why doesn't the random number changes when the `DateTime.Now.Millisecond` change? Please note I just started learning C# so I am sorry if I made a lot of mistakes.

Comment: `Random` is actually deterministic so creating a new `Random` object in a tight loop will result in similar values (the default seed used is derived from the system clock which doesn't change enough within such a short period of time to create a new seed value). Create one instance of  `Random` outside the loop and reuse that object. `Random rn = new Random(); while (true) ... `

Comment: From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) **`Avoiding multiple instantiations`** `...to avoid inadvertently creating separate random number generators that generate identical numeric sequences, we recommend that you create one Random object to generate many random numbers over time`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,bb77e610694e64ca), the parameterless constructor is defined as:

```
  public Random() 
    : this(Environment.TickCount) {
  }
```

Which means that it doesn't use the `DateTime.Now.Millisecond` as the seed, but rather the `Environment.TickCount` value.

So if you write your code like this:

```
Random rn;
while (true)
{
    rn = new Random();
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.TickCount);
    Console.WriteLine(rn.Next(10));
}
```

It should produce the expected output. Try it!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear answer! And the code produces the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-random numbers are chosen with equal probability from a finite set of numbers. The chosen numbers are not completely random because a mathematical algorithm is used to select them, but they are sufficiently random for practical purposes. The current implementation of the Random class is based on a modified version of Donald E. Knuth's subtractive random number generator algorithm.

Every time you do new Random() it is initialized using the clock. This means that in a tight loop you get the same value lots of times. You should keep a single Random instance and keep using Next on the same instance.

try this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rn= new Random();
            while (true)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(rn.Next(10));
            }

    }
```